# How to replace double quotes in a json string in Golang?

Tags: json, regex, go, regexp-replace

I have a problem parsing a string object to JSON with Golang.

there are double quotes in some fields values.

I'm trying to use a regex pattern but it doesn't work for me, I'm doing the conversion from bigquery which is based on the Golang code but it doesn't work for me.

```
{
                    "Responses": [],
                    "SessionParameters(Updated)": {
                        "counter-no-match-nombre": "($session.params.counter-no-match, 1)",
                        "message": "Hello."
                    },
                    "SystemFunctionResults": {
                        "SystemFunctionErrors": [
                            {
                                "Message": "Wrong type of argument for function "NONE", expected 1th argument to be one of type: ["number"]."
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

here a example

([:[,{]\s*)"(.*?)"(?=\s*[:,]}])

[Test regex](https://regex101.com/r/F2qT8J/1)

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('{
    "obj1": "value is "test" of test, \"obj1\" val",
    "result": "your result is "out" in our website",
    "info": {
        "x": [
            {
                "desc": "shjjfdsajfjkfsdkf, "sfsdfsdfdsf" fjkdfgjkfd."
            }
        ]
    }
}','([:\\[,{]\\s*)"(.*?)"(?:\\s*[:,\\]}])','NONE') 
  AS json_data;
```

I would appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: What is not working exactly? Is the replacement not leading the proper result or is the regex pattern wrong given the returned results?

Comment: Not-escaped double quotes inside double quotes... that is not valid JSON, in fact that is not valid *anything* (probably). You should ditch the source from which you got that piece of data, and instead use something that follows reason.

Comment: @tmarwen

the pattern of does not work to be able to remove the double quotes in a string with json format

Comment: @mkopriva
 The data source is the Google log record system, so I need to carry out the procedure with that data.

Comment: Something is mangling the json before this step, because that is not parse-able. Rather than guessing what the strings looked like before, it would be better to figure out what is breaking the json in the first place.